# PHP - Not able to read XML node values

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am getting below SOAP API response and trying to read XML node value but not getting `resultcode` & `message` values.

```
$result = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <tic:reservationresponse xmlns:tic="http://example.com/">
            <tic:reservationresp>
                <tic:resultcode>-204</tic:resultcode>
                <tic:message>Invalid Location Id</tic:message>
            </tic:reservationresp>
        </tic:reservationresponse>
    </soap:body>
</soapenv:envelope>';

$xml     = simplexml_load_string($result);
$soapenv = $xml->children("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$tns     = $soapenv->Body->children("http://example.com/");

echo $tns->reservationresponse->reservationresp->resultcode;
```

What I am doing wrong. Any Idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably kick yourself, but the tag names are case-sensitive. You just need to change

```
$tns = $soapenv->Body->children("http://example.com/");
```

to:

```
$tns = $soapenv->body->children("http://example.com/");
```